# How to put # in mediawiki

Tags: syntax, mediawiki

It seems if I put # in mediawiki, then # in and of itself has mediawiki internal meaning.

I researched a bit and I found that I can put ♯.

And then later I tried

```
<nowiki>#</nowiki>
```

but this just didn't work or even broke some tables.

I thought  will make the mediawiki understand that "#" is just plain text, not any command or function or whatever. But perhaps I was wrong.

How can I put # ?

Comment: I think that `<nowiki>#</nowiki>` should work. Could you post an example where it didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the character code entity &#35;